# Docker compose linking to mariaDB

Tags: docker, mariadb, docker-compose

I’m trying to create a basic development machine running `php7`, `nginx` and `mariaDB`, using `docker-compose`.

The stripped down version of my compose file is as follows:

```
wwwroot:
 container_name: wwwroot
 image: wwwroot
 volumes:
  - .:/var/www
 restart: always
nginx:
 container_name: nginx
 image: nginx
 links:
  - php70  
 volumes_from:
  - wwwroot
 ports:
  - "80:80"
  - "443:443"
 restart: always
php70:
 container_name: php70
 image: kreable/php70
 volumes_from:
  - wwwroot
 links:
  - mariadb
 restart: always
mariadb:
 container_name: mariadb
 image: mariadb
 environment:
  DB_ADMIN_PASS: pass
 ports:
  - "3306:3306"
 restart: always
```

This works fine and creates the desired containers. The problem comes with trying to connect a basic PHP script to the database. I always get:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

My PHP application is in the `wwwroot` container.

Do have I to do any further configuration to allow my PHP application to connect to the mariaDB container?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you have setup a link from `php70` to the `mariadb` container, but you don't have one in the `wwwroot` container. If you are trying to connect from your wwwroot container, then you will need to add a link to mariadb from there as well. Or it looks like you probably want to be connecting to your php70 container instead.

Also, it might be good to show the PHP code that you are using to try and connect to mariadb, that is causing the error.

Comment: The php script is a simple `PDO` based connection. I'm trying to connect to `127.0.0.1` with `root` and `pass` as the username/password.

Comment: Can you add that code snippet to your question, it will make it easier to see if you have a bug in that code. Also, you shouldn't be trying to connect to `127.0.0.1`, you should be trying to connect to `mariadb` since localhost won't let you leave the container, and docker will create a dns alias called mariadb that will link to the mariadb container. Also, make sure you are using the correct port 3306.